# json import breaks down but from same server source

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am exploring the ajax synchronous json import into my javascript code.

The JSON source link I want to use is

> http://www.nusantech.com/hendak/default.php?m=galaksi&galaksi=1&viewID=1&t=json

But to keep server loads down, a week ago or so I created a static page showing the same data at

> http://www.nusantech.com/hendak/noobjson.php

My javascript import is as below:

```
<head>
    <title>Nusantech</title>
    <script src="\OpenLayers213\OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jsonData = {};
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://hendak.seribudaya.com/noobjson.php",
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                jsonData = data;
            }
    });
alert("Galaksi value retrieved from JSON (expected: 1) : "+jsonData.galaksi);
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function kemasMaklumat(id,content) {
            var container = document.getElementById(id);
            container.innerHTML = content;
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

From there I retrieve the values I want on jsonData, eg, (x,y) coordinates as

```
(jsonData.planets[7].coordinates[0].x,jsonData.planets[7].coordinates[0].y)
```

It works fine with the noobjson.php link, but when I point it back to default.php, nothing appears. The page took a while to load which make it seem like its loading the json values, but the `alert("Galaksi value retrieved")` returns `undefined`.

I copy & pasted the output from the default.php page on a JSON verifier on the web and it showed OK. I don't know why the static link works but the `$_GET` based link doesn't.

Can someone suggest me what is happening?

EDIT

I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsonData = {};
    $.ajax({
//          url: "http://hendak.seribudaya.com/noobjson.php",
            url:  "http://hendak.seribudaya.com/default.php?"+encodeURIComponent("galaksi=1&viewID=1&m=galaksi&t=json"),
//          url:  "http://hendak.seribudaya.com/default.php?galaksi=1&viewID=1&m=galaksi&t=json",
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(data) {
                jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(eval("("+data+")")));
                alert("Success");
                },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("Failed to download info." + data);
                }
        });
    </SCRIPT>
enter code here
```

I always get the Failed to download info unless I use the noobjson URL.

It is as if that URL with the GET doesn't exist.

Comment: *sidenote:* use `/` instead of backslash in JS path

Comment: You can start debugging by comparing server responses of two URLs.

Comment: I changed the backslash into /.\n

I still can't get it working. I've checked both the response of the two URLs, I can't figure it out.

I checked the output of the http://www.nusantech.com/hendak/default.php?m=galaksi&galaksi=1&viewID=1&t=json using an online JSON validator 
at http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html and it returned : 
The JSON input is valid in JavaScript.
The JSON input is valid according to RFC 4627 (JSON specfication).

I don't see why its giving problems.

Comment: Also, I copied the output from the default.php URL and pasted it into a new empty file, and I was able to import the JSON details from this new file.

It seems I can only import JSON from a static file but not a dynamically generated file. Is this normal?

Comment: curious: Did you encode your URL (the one with GET parameters) before making AJAX call ?

Comment: Hi, that could be the problem, as I have no idea what that means. In that url, all I did was php echo all the output. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it.

In the default.php, what I have done was:

```
if ($_GET["t"]=="json") {
    $viewID=$_GET["viewID"];
    $galaksi=$_GET["galaksi"];
    $con=mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $database); 
    $sql="SELECT Hari FROM berita WHERE Galaksi=".$galaksi;
    $hari=1;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); while(($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) ){$hari=$row['Hari']; } 
    $lb="";
    if ($_GET["t"]!="json") { echo "<PRE>\n"; $lb="\n"; }
    echo "{\"galaksi\": ".$galaksi.",";
    echo $lb."\"hari\": ".$hari.",";
    echo $lb."\"planets\": [";
    //etc
    //etc
}
```

So I replaced all the individual echoes with $JSONstr like below.

```
if ($_GET["t"]=="json") {
    $viewID=$_GET["viewID"];
    $galaksi=$_GET["galaksi"];
    $con=mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $database); 
    $sql="SELECT Hari FROM berita WHERE Galaksi=".$galaksi;
    $hari=1;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); while(($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) ){$hari=$row['Hari']; } 
    $lb="";
    $JSONstr="";
//  if ($_GET["t"]!="json") { $JSONstr="<PRE>\n"; $lb="\n"; }
    $JSONstr=$JSONstr."{\"galaksi\": ".$galaksi.",";
    $JSONstr=$JSONstr.$lb."\"hari\": ".$hari.",";
    $JSONstr=$JSONstr.$lb."\"planets\": [";
    //etc
    //etc
    //and at the end:
        echo $JSONstr;
}
```

Then I added the echo $JSONstr; at the end. Originally I did that so that I can do :

```
 echo json_encode($JSONstr);
```

but this creates {\"Galaksi\" : 1} at the JSON output instead of the intended { "Galaksi": 1 }

So I removed the json_encode and just output the string.
Also I had to remove the

```
if ($_GET["t"]!="json"){ $JSONstr="<PRE>\n"; $lb="\n"; }
```

I also used a different JSON tester this time.

Originally I used http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html which says JSON Valid for my initial JSON output. Then I used this one, which said that my JSON output url was invalid, although if I copy+paste the output string it returned valid. http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

So after making those changes and removing the `"<PRE>"`, the curiousconcept validator gave me a valid status.

Then I used this in the javascript, and I am now able to retrieve expected values.

Thank you all, hope this helps someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode the URL component before sending the request. Try:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://www.nusantech.com/hendak/default.php?" + encodeURIComponent('m=galaksi&galaksi=1&viewID=1&t=json'),
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            jsonData = data;
        }
});
```

Reference: [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: This still doesn't work. It is as if that URL doesn't exist at all. Please view another edit on the original question.